# Set A User's Cover Photo with Facebook API

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to create a Facebook application that provides users a number of different options to set their cover photo. The platform I use to build the app only accepts javascript. Can anyone provide direction as to how to accomplish this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? It would help if you show that you've done some research or work into your problem and ask something more specific to what is blocking you. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

What I would consider the correct documentation of the current OpenGraph API is here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/cover-photo/

That page clearly says that there are no create, update, nor delete options for such.

There is also a way by getting all the album identifiers and then using the `<album-id>/photos` call. However, when you use that with the `<album-id>` of the cover album, you get a **403 Forbidden** error.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/album/photos

So it sounds pretty clear that changing the cover photo directly is not possible.

However, your application can still post a photo to its own album, and then send the user to that photo with the following URL:

```
http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?preview_cover=PHOTO_ID
```

To post a photo to you application album, you can just use "me":

```
// retrieve authorization, we need the token
var auth = FB.getAuthResponse();

// create the variable parameters to be sent
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("access_token", auth.accessToken);
//fd.append("source", blob); -- this requires a binary image in blob
fd.append("url", "http://example.com/cute.jpg");
fd.append("message", "Message user entered (no pre-fill allowed!)");
fd.append("no_story", false);

// now send that URI to Facebook
$.ajax({
    url: "https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=" + auth.accessToken,
      type: "POST",
      data: fd,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        console.log("Post to album succeeded");
        console.log(data);

        // send the user to change his cover photo with the photo you just uploaded
        window.location = "http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?preview_cover=" + data.id;
      },
      error: function(shr, status, data) {
        console.log("error");
        console.log(shr);
        console.log(status);
        console.log(data);
      },
      complete: function() {
        console.log("Posting to facebook complete");
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the Cover photo via the Graph API. Have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user#nopublishupdatedelete as a reference.